# Include the first lag of all variables in regression

Tags: r, regression, lag

I am looking for a way to include all variables of a data frame AND their within-group first  lags in a regression model. My data has a shape similar to this:

```
df <- data.frame(group = c('A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B'),
                 y= 11:18,
                 x1= 21:28,
                 x2= 1:8)
df
    group  y      x1      x2
1     A     11     21      1
2     A     12     22      2
3     A     13     23      3
4     A     14     24      4
5     B     15     25      5
6     B     16     26      6
7     B     17     27      7
8     B     18     28      8
```

I want to include x1 and x2 as regressors as well as their respective first lags. It is important that the lags of x1 and x2 stay within their groups A and B (i.e. I am not interested in the difference between rows 5 and 4).

However my real dataset includes more than 150 variables so the approach to manually add the lagged values as a new variable to the data frame (e.g. `df <- df %>% group_by(group) %>% mutate(value1_lag = lag(value1))` is not feasable.

Instead I am looking for something along the lines of

`model <- dyn$lmf(y ~ . + lag(.), data = df)`

however it does not seem to work with the simple lag() operator.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: `lag()` from what package?

Answer (score 2):

You could add the variables all at once using `across`:

```r
df <- data.frame(group = c('A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B'),
                 y= 11:18,
                 x1= 21:28,
                 x2= 1:8)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(time = row_number(), 
         lag = across(-c(y, time), lag)) %>% 
  unnest(lag, names_sep = "_") %>%
  arrange(group, time) %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("lag_"), ~case_when(time == 1 ~ lead(.x), 
                                                TRUE ~ .x)))
#> # A tibble: 8 × 7
#> # Groups:   group [2]
#>   group     y    x1    x2  time lag_x1 lag_x2
#>   <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int>  <int>  <int>
#> 1 A        11    21     1     1     21      1
#> 2 A        12    22     2     2     21      1
#> 3 A        13    23     3     3     22      2
#> 4 A        14    24     4     4     23      3
#> 5 B        15    25     5     1     25      5
#> 6 B        16    26     6     2     25      5
#> 7 B        17    27     7     3     26      6
#> 8 B        18    28     8     4     27      7
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot! That works great. Is there a way to set the NA to the first value of each group-rows? Like `mutate(lag = across(-y, lag(,first())`

Comment: What do you mean by "set the NA to the first rows", do you mean to organize the data so that the first rows are all the first time-point?

Comment: I don't want any NA's in my dataframe but I also don't want to simply delet rows including NA's. I would like to imput all the NA's with the first original value of the variable. One example: df[1,5] is now NA, in my solution it would be a 21 because the first value of x1 = 21. Along the same line: df[5,5] is now NA but should be a 25.

Comment: @martinim I cannot vouch for the statistical properties of doing that, but the mechanics are not that difficult.  I updated my answer to include that.  Once the lag is created, it's just a separate `mutate()` statement to fill in the missing first values with the one-period lead of the lagged value.  It's a bit confusing (using the lead of the lag), but it makes the code easier to read.

Comment: you are correct in being worried about the statistical properties of doing that if the intention is to run a model on this new dataset. The observations are no longer independent

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems in the question:

1. dyn is not the right package for longitudinal data.
2. The df shown in the question is not a good example because the columns are linearly dependent due to the use of linear sequences so try this example where we will use mpg in mtcars as the dependent variable, cyl as the grouping variable and hp and disp as the independent variables.

Note that there are multiple lag versions in different packages and also in base R so we explicitly refer to which one we want each time.

**1) plm** The plm package has facilities specifically for panel data.  First add a time column and then use plm. The plm model= argument can provide for many other possibilities.  plm assumes that the first column is the group and the second column is time.

```
library(plm)

mtcars2 <- transform(mtcars, time = ave(1:nrow(mtcars), cyl, FUN = seq_along))

indep <- names(mtcars2)[3:4]

L01 <- function(x) plm::lag(x, 0:1)
fo <- reformulate(sprintf("L01(%s)", indep), "mpg")
fo
## mpg ~ L01(disp) + L01(hp)

plm(fo, data = mtcars2, index = c("cyl", "time"), model = "pooling")
```

giving:

```
Model Formula: mpg ~ L01(disp) + L01(hp)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)  L01(disp)0  L01(disp)1    L01(hp)0    L01(hp)1 
 31.0212451  -0.0327843  -0.0019717  -0.0243698   0.0051201
```

**2) lm**  Compute the lagged variables using dplyr, the formula using reformulate and then invoke lm.

```
library(dplyr)

indep <- names(mtcars2)[3:4]

mtcars2 <- mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl = factor(cyl)) %>%
  mutate(across(all_of(indep), dplyr::lag, .names = "lag.{col}")) %>%
  ungroup

fo <- reformulate(c(indep, paste0("lag.", indep)), "mpg")
fo
## mpg ~ disp + hp + lag.disp + lag.hp

lm(fo, mtcars2, na.action = na.exclude)
```

giving the same coefficients:

```
Call:
lm(formula = fo, data = mtcars2, na.action = na.exclude)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)         disp           hp     lag.disp       lag.hp  
  31.021245    -0.032784    -0.024370    -0.001972     0.005120
```

### Update

Reorganized answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could `grep` the names of your regressors into vector `xn`, split the data `by` group, apply the lag function with a careful `setNames`, `rbind`.

```
xn <- grep('^X', names(dat), value=TRUE)

dat <- by(dat, dat$group, \(X) {
  cbind(X, setNames(as.data.frame(lapply(X[xn], \(x) c(NA, x[-length(x)]))), paste0(xn, '.lag1')))
}) |> do.call(what='rbind')
```

Then just `reformulate` while `grep`ing again with the `collapse=`d `xn`.

```
lm(reformulate(grep(paste(xn, collapse='|'), names(dat), value=TRUE), 'Y'), dat) |>
  summary() 
# Call:
# lm(formula = reformulate(grep(paste(xn, collapse = "|"), names(dat), 
#                                 value = TRUE), "Y"), data = dat)
# 
# Residuals:
#      Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
# -1.85222 -0.31818  0.05702  0.33261  1.01141 
# 
# Coefficients:
#             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)   0.6775     0.1768   3.832 0.000231 ***
# X1            1.5754     0.1688   9.335 5.22e-15 ***
# X2            2.5787     0.1750  14.737  < 2e-16 ***
# X1.lag1       0.7651     0.1652   4.630 1.18e-05 ***
# X2.lag1       1.9722     0.1777  11.098  < 2e-16 ***
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# Residual standard error: 0.4892 on 93 degrees of freedom
# (2 observations deleted due to missingness)
# Multiple R-squared:  0.8234,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.8158 
# F-statistic: 108.4 on 4 and 93 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(X1 = c(0.915, 0.937, 0.286, 0.83, 0.642, 0.519, 
0.737, 0.135, 0.657, 0.705, 0.458, 0.719, 0.935, 0.255, 0.462, 
0.94, 0.978, 0.117, 0.475, 0.56, 0.904, 0.139, 0.989, 0.947, 
0.082, 0.514, 0.39, 0.906, 0.447, 0.836, 0.738, 0.811, 0.388, 
0.685, 0.004, 0.833, 0.007, 0.208, 0.907, 0.612, 0.38, 0.436, 
0.037, 0.974, 0.432, 0.958, 0.888, 0.64, 0.971, 0.619, 0.852, 
0.443, 0.158, 0.442, 0.968, 0.485, 0.252, 0.26, 0.542, 0.65, 
0.336, 0.061, 0.451, 0.839, 0.575, 0.353, 0.547, 0.893, 0.49, 
0.172, 0.543, 0.961, 0.314, 0.821, 0.307, 0.185, 0.048, 0.246, 
0.351, 0.159, 0.304, 0.018, 0.997, 0.804, 0.087, 0.87, 0.555, 
0.421, 0.068, 0.561, 0.071, 0.211, 0.55, 0.482, 0.159, 0.15, 
0.499, 0.941, 0.334, 0.188), X2 = c(0.333, 0.347, 0.398, 0.785, 
0.039, 0.749, 0.677, 0.171, 0.261, 0.514, 0.676, 0.983, 0.76, 
0.566, 0.85, 0.189, 0.271, 0.828, 0.693, 0.241, 0.043, 0.14, 
0.216, 0.479, 0.197, 0.719, 0.008, 0.375, 0.514, 0.002, 0.582, 
0.158, 0.359, 0.646, 0.776, 0.564, 0.234, 0.09, 0.086, 0.305, 
0.667, 0, 0.209, 0.933, 0.926, 0.734, 0.333, 0.515, 0.744, 0.619, 
0.27, 0.531, 0.021, 0.799, 0.11, 0.54, 0.571, 0.619, 0.715, 0.123, 
0.311, 0.946, 0.5, 0.135, 0.869, 0.205, 0.925, 0.887, 0.136, 
0.785, 0.453, 0.136, 0.885, 0.337, 0.319, 0.404, 0.479, 0.368, 
0.466, 0.05, 0.187, 0.983, 0.328, 0.171, 0.488, 0.019, 0.339, 
0.03, 0.867, 0.732, 0.315, 0.386, 0.332, 0.09, 0.757, 0.603, 
0.145, 0.033, 0.484, 0.445), Y = c(3.499, 5.284, 3.72, 5.143, 
3.938, 4.344, 5.567, 1.378, 2.717, 3.949, 4.769, 6.487, 7.533, 
4.3, 5.513, 4.778, 4.609, 4.701, 5.164, 3.182, 2.933, 2.001, 
2.57, 4.482, 2.953, 4.048, 2.989, 2.901, 3.544, 3.909, 4.188, 
4.041, 2.92, 3.816, 4.618, 4.804, 2.585, 1.627, 2.869, 3.913, 
3.746, 2.912, 1.832, 4.645, 6.05, 5.835, 4.471, 4.419, 6.171, 
6.155, 3.79, 3.859, 2.571, 2.721, 4.324, 3.452, 3.792, 4.636, 
4.482, 3.432, 3.037, 3.83, 4.799, 4.377, 4.026, 4.404, 4.303, 
6.612, 4.414, 4.023, 3.419, 4.627, 4.849, 4.603, 2.815, 3.36, 
3.341, 3.085, 3.44, 2.349, 2.222, 3.909, 4.596, 3.231, 3.66, 
3.347, 2.823, 2.017, 3.485, 4.754, 3.952, 2.139, 2.819, 3.519, 
3.637, 4.422, 4.153, 2.96, 2.407, 3.646), group = c("A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B")), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = "data.frame")
```